Firebase in-app messaging button action does not working
On ios with flutter
I have set the action of the "ok" button to "https://www.google.com/", but when I open the app on ios, the test notification modal shows up, but when I click on the ok button, the modal closes and the google.com link is not opened. I want to know what is my problem
enter image description here
I want when I press the "ok" button, the google.com link is opened

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To fixed issues: remove import pkg: https://pub.dev/documentation/uni_links/latest/

This is init firebase in app
import 'package:firebase_in_app_messaging/firebase_in_app_messaging.dart';
    
    class FirebaseInAppMsg {
      FirebaseInAppMsg();
    
      Future initialise() async {
        FirebaseInAppMessaging.instance;
      }
    }

and i used:
FirebaseInAppMsg firebaseMessaging = FirebaseInAppMsg();
await firebaseMessaging.initialise();

Same as:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started
